# How to install bower package with a slash in the name?

Tags: bower, jquery-knob, bower-install

I'm trying to install https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob through bower. In the bower.json file of the package I see:

`{
  "name": "aterrien/jQuery-Knob",
  "version": "1.2.9",
  ..
}`

So in my bower.json file I put in:

```
"aterrien/jQuery-Knob": "1.2.9"
```

When I run `bower install` I'm getting this:

```
bower jQuery-Knob#1.2.9         cached aterrien/jQuery-Knob=https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob.git#1.2.9
bower jQuery-Knob#1.2.9       validate 1.2.9 against aterrien/jQuery-Knob=https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob.git#1.2.9
bower jQuery-Knob#1.2.9        ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads a terrien/jQuery-Knob=https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: I don't handle protocol 'aterrien/jQuery-Knob=https'
```

Why is it prepending the package name to the protocol? And how should I install this package?

Answer (score 6):

had same problem with this plugin,
remove it and install like this:

> bower install jquery-knob

notice the lowercase and no need for the 'aterrien/'

it worked for me